# intranet colaboration system

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, intranet

I would like to give our intranet users and create, edit, colaborate documents via a browser.  What is the best way to go about this?

```
Requirements: The user should be able to:
1. create content,
2. edit content (content created by anyone)
3. records should be kept on who edited what and when
4. should easily be able to go back and forth between edits
5. should be able to assign rights to created/edited pages (i.e. who can view them)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly all Wiki-engines works like that.

Comment: Well, there are plenty of good ones at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software  Take a look at PHP-based ones, should be easiest to install.  Personally, I use internal wiki in Redmine project managing system, but they all have similar functional.

Comment: Also, take a look at ietherpad.com :-)

Comment: ietherpad.com looks good.  Is there something similar which I can host on my own server?

Comment: It's opensource, you can install it on your server.

Comment: I can't see an option to let me download and install it on my own server and get it to connect to my database.

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend [flexwiki](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexwiki/), a breeze to install and you can dive into the source code to change what doesn't suit you. it's been out of updates since a while now, but there's only so much you can add to a wiki...

Apart from that, you could use the google apps suite, their collaborative work is really good. You can have them hosted on your servers, but i don't know anything about their pricing and use terms

Comment: Is it possible to somehow integrate google wave into our intranet as a private network collaborative environment?

Comment: It's nearing it's end of life, servers will be shut down soon.

Comment: I was thinking more about google documents, but wave is indeed dyingish. You can host a server though since the protocol is fully open and apparently open sources solutions are out there. Didn't know that etherpad was open-source, so that may also be a good idea :) In any case, a wiki works fine too ^^